# How to Mount a folder without sharing it in Xp

Tags: windows-xp, mount

I have a few folders that I refer to quite often. These folders are often deep in the folder tree. For example: *E:\Work\Dec2009\rasters* or something like that.

Is there a way to mount this folder as a new drive, so that I can quickly access it using **My Computer**?

I know that we can mount shared folders as network drives and they appear in **My Computer**; Is there a similar way to mount folders on your own computer without sharing the folder in question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use SUBST, which is like drive mapping except it works with local paths rather than UNC paths.

In a command prompt or .bat/.cmd file:

```
subst x: E:\Work\Dec2009\rasters
```

To remove:

```
subst /d x:
```

Note that the drives created by subst are not persistent, so you'll have to create a .bat/.cmd file and place a shortcut in your StartUp group if you want this to be applied every time you log on.

Comment: OT: ah, good old subst. I remember back in the day when games where on disk and you could circumvent copy protection among other things with subst :)

Comment: that's nifty - never heard of `subst` before

Comment: This is a nice trick. I really like your answer because it doesn't require any additional software.

Comment: @warren, you'd be surprised how many seasoned Windows users have never heard of subst, and it's been around since the MS DOS days already. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not as cool as [Graeme's](https://superuser.com/users/5392/) [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/77801/how-to-mount-a-folder-without-sharing-it-in-xp/77807#77807), I would have been inclined to make a shortcut to the folder on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

While using the subst command is a cute little trick (+1!), the number of drive letters is limited. Perhaps a 'directory hotlist' might suit you:

My tool of choice is **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** - simply hit **CTRL + D** to add a location to the "Directory Hotlist"

If you fancy something more 'graphical', have a look at **[Standalone Stack](http://www.chrisnsoft.com/standalonestack/)**

[image]

There is also **[Anvir Task Manager Free](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm)**, which automatically populates a list (accessible from tray icon) showing the most recently opened folders (folders can be added manually to this list).

[image]